# C#, Every 30 secs i need to update the windows form by finding how many time the for loop iterated in last X minutes

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I need to fetch messages from a remote queue(websphere MQ), i do it by finding the No of total messages from the queue and iterate by using for loop , while the processing is going on i need to find how many messages i have fetched in last 5mins and i need to update a text box in windows forms for every 30secs. I think this might give a clear vision. i need a logic to find this as i'm new to this..

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) And why this question tagged with `asp.net`?

Comment: [This is really a bad title..](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title)

Comment: Possible dublicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15781167/c-every-30-secs-i-need-to-update-the-windows-form-by-finding-the-last-fives-mi

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/faq please refer this

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Timer to do this

http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.threading.timer.aspx